# Как изменить цвет текста в Menu

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте!

Как изменить цвет текста в MenuItem WPF? Задание свойства Foreground в нужный цвет результата не даёт

```
<Menu Background="LightSlateGray" Foreground="White">
    <MenuItem Header="{Resx Menu_File}">
        <MenuItem Header="{Resx Menu_File_Exit}" Command="{Binding CmdExit}"/>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если Вам дан правильный ответ, то отметьте его как правильный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Menu Background="LightSlateGray" Foreground="White">
  <MenuItem Header="{Resx Menu_File}" Foreground="Red">
      <MenuItem Header="{Resx Menu_File_Exit}" Command="{Binding CmdExit}" Foreground="Blue"/>
  </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Заметил, что если в родительском MenuItem Foreground не поменять, а в дочернем поменять, то в дочернем цвет не изменится. Нужно обязательно установить Foreground и в родительском MenuItem, и в дочернем

Answer (score 2):

```
<Menu>
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <Style  TargetType="MenuItem">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
        <MenuItem Header="Open"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Save"/>
        <MenuItem Header="Save as..."/>
        <MenuItem Header="Exit" />
        </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]